# Expandable listview child position restarts for each header

Tags: java, android, eclipse, expandablelistview

I have expandable listview and everytime I click a child, I determine what's going to open according to ChildPosition. However the problem is that ChildPosition resets for "headre row". For example I have Header 1 and Header 2 and both headers have 4 childs. Child1's position under header 1 is 0 and child1's position under header  2 is also 0.

This ruins my code since I always pass ChildPosition as extra to the next activity and a different WebView opens according to that int. Here's the code:

Passing extra:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, int childPosition, long arg4) {
            //Starting intent
            Intent scheudele = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scheudele.class);
            scheudele.putExtra("razred", childPosition);
            startActivity(scheudele);
            Log.i("TAG", "Position: " + childPosition);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Using that extra to load url:

```
public void getWebView(){
    razredData = getIntent();
    int position = razredData.getIntExtra("razred", 0);
    String urlToLoad = null;

    switch (position){
    case 0:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/16515/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 1:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/16520/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 2:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/16516/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 3:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/16517/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 4:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/16518/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 5:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18222/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 6:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18223/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 7:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18224/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 8:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18225/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 9:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18215/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 10:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18216/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 11:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18217/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 12:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18219/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 13:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18220/0/0/1";
        break;
    case 14:
        urlToLoad = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/18221/0/0/1";
        break;
    }

    //Loading WebView URL
    webView.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}
```

So, as you can already imagine; if I click childs under Header 1, the correct url is shown but after I start clicking childs under Header 2, their position resets to 0 and it shows the "case 0" url again. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onChildClick()` there is also parameter `int groupPosition`, but you have it as `int arg2`.

Then you can pass groupPosition as extras and decide also by groupPosition which url to load.

See the documentation of OnChildClickListener:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html